# Targeting a link inside of a <h3> tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to target the text inside of these code snippets

```
<ul>
    <h3 class="headp">
        <a href="#" class="mininav"  onclick="switchContent('sub1'); return false;">Marking Products</a>
    </h3>
    <li class="ulfp">
        <a href="#top" class="mininav" onclick="switchContent('sub2'); return false;">Specialty Cheese Product    Markings</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My h3 .headp class does not affect my text so I assume I am not correctly targeting the text. What am I missing?

Comment: What did you try? Put some code to let us what you did please.

Comment: your links are inside your h3, not the other way around... and the `h3/a` stuff is totally illegal anyways. it's inside a `<ul>`, but outside of a `<li>`. that is INVALID html.

Comment: Are you trying to select with `h3 .headp` or `h3.headp`? If you have a space between `h3` and `.heap` then that's your main error (appart from invalid html).

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the info. Can you tell me why that is invalid?

Comment: i was trying to select with .headp, I did fix the h3/li issue putting my header outside of my ul tag

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of approaching this layout.

Replace the `h3` by `li` to keep the HTML syntax correct, and then use the `.headp` class to format the first `li` as a header.

To change the color of the link, you need a separate CSS rule, `.headp a`, see below.

Alternatively, you could have wrapped the `h3` block in a `li`.

```css
.headp {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.00em;
  margin: 20px 0;
 }
.headp a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="headp">
        <a href="#" class="mininav"  onclick="switchContent('sub1'); return false;">Marking Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ulfp">
        <a href="#top" class="mininav" onclick="switchContent('sub2'); return false;">Specialty Cheese Product    Markings</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```